# How to Solve Injections In Constructor With Base Handler Class In CQRS .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, cqrs

I am trying to create a CQRS-patterned application. I have handler classes to manage my business logic. But the handler constructors have many dependency and this leads to a lot of boilerplate. Is there any solution that allows me to inject all these items in a base handler class and make my handler more pure?

```cs
public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command>
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly string _value;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IEventBus _bus;

    public Handler(
        DataContext context,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IMapper mapper,
        IEventBus bus)
    {
        _context = context;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _bus = bus;

        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
            _value = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["Value"].ToString();
    }

    public async Task<Unit> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (true) return Unit.Value;

        throw new Exception("Error Message");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could create and additional service that holds the dependencies. That you'd have to inject only this. But imho, this often leads to injecting more services that really required and so I'd simply inject what you need, when you need it, without any base class.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Thank you for your kind answer. How can i find an example or tutorial about this solution ?

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with @Stelios's answer. Try to solve the root problem, which is a Single Responsibility Principle violation. [Section 6.1](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-6/section-6-1) of [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl) (my book) actually discusses this problem (and possible solutions) in detail.

Comment: Also prevent using dependencies from inside the constructor (as you do with the `IHttpContextAccessor`), as Mark Seemann described [here](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). Al kinds of (subtle) problems can arise from this.

Comment: Hi @Steven. I really want to thank so much to you. Because you spend your time and write so many valuable informations about my problem. I ve checked all documents that you sent me and all were so helpfull. I really appreciate about it. Thank you again

Comment: @Steven I have actually read your book! It is very well written, congrats! I have recommended it to many colleagues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common problem.

It is addressed very well with the [Facade Pattern](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-core/1469/facade-pattern) or Facade services.

What you do is you create a new service that works as a wrapper for the rest. In this way you inject only one service.

**Single responsibility principle alert**

You inject too many services in your class and this is typical code smell for [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) abuse. You should try to split your functionality in different classes. That would help you write cleaner code.

Comment: Also see the [Facade Service Refactoring pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).

Comment: Stelios Thank you so much for your answer. I just noticed that pattern is something that i ve used before in previous projects. I didnt know that is a patter and its name is Facade. I think i just confused about it because i m using CQRS but by the this way i belive that i will solve the problem.